# Capital letter typing not possible in sikuli

Tags: java, sikuli

​I want to type in capital letters​ and am using Sikuli jar with Java, but when i type it gets typed in small letters.

```
Screen xc = new Screen();
xc.click(new Pattern("C:\abcd.png");
xc.type("Moon");
```

abcd.png is the image for test box. Is is able to click on test box and then typing it always types moon with m in small letters instead of capital letters in text box

Comment: Check your caps lock button

Comment: I want to do it by my script and not by pressing manually Caps Lock button

Comment: I just meant for you to make sure your caps lock isn't pressed. This is the first thing that comes to my mind as the scenario you are describing is obviously not reproducible as it is. There must be something that you overlooked.

Answer (score 0):

You can invoke a method to check if caps lock is on\off and toggle it accordingly

```
    def _capslock(self):
    test = Env.isLockOn(Key.CAPS_LOCK)
    if test:
        type(Key.CAPS_LOCK)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of typing you could try to simply paste the text in rather than typing.

```
    xc.paste("Moon")
```

While the type should work, this may be a simple work around.